# Load Avro file data to snowflake using merge query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, avro, snowflake-schema

I have one avro file, and I am trying to insert its contents to snowflake table using merge query.

Avro file is **test.avro.gz**, which could have semi structured data.
If I convert the this file to json, it would have data like:
Example:

```
{
    "ID" : 16,
    "VISITS" : 2,
    "DATE" : 1623801600,
    "DIMENSIONS" : [
        {
            "index" : 17,
            "value" : "(none)"
        }
    ],
    "TYPE" : "VISIT",
}
{
    "ID" : 18,
    "VISITS" : 4,
    "DATE" : 1623801600,
    "DIMENSIONS" : [
        {
            "index" : 7,
            "value" : "(none)"
        }
    ],
    "TYPE" : "VISIT",
}
```

I have created a file format and a temporary stage as:

```
snowflake_client.run("create or replace file format test_format type = 'avro'")
stage_name = f"test_{snowflake_client.generate_random_string()}"
create_stage = f"CREATE TEMPORARY STAGE {stage_name} COMMENT = 'TEMPORARY STAGE FOR test table DATA LOAD'"
snowflake_client.run(create_stage)
snowflake_client.run(f"put file://test.avro.gz @{stage_name} PARALLEL=16")
```

The merge query that I am using is:

```
query = f"MERGE INTO TEST USING (SELECT $1 ID, $2 VISITS,$3 DATE, $6 TOTALS, $7 TRAFFICSOURCE
           FROM @{stage_name} (file_format => 'test_format'))
           TEMP_STAGE ON TEST.ID= TEMP_STAGE.ID and TEST.VISITS=TEMP_STAGE.VISITS 
           WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ID,VISITS,DATE,TOTALS,DIMENSIONS,TYPE) VALUES 
           (TEMP_STAGE.ID,TEMP_STAGE.VISITS,TEMP_STAGE.DATE,TEMP_STAGE.DIMENSIONS,
           TEMP_STAGE.TYPE);"
                                                          
                                                            
snowflake_client.run(query)
```

What I want is data to be unique on ID and VISITS, hence I am using merge instead of copy.

The snowflake table would have data like:

```
 ID   VISITS   DATE             DIMENSIONS                           TYPE
 16   2      1623801600         [{"index" : 17,"value" : "(none)"}]   VISIT
```

The error I am getting is:

```
**AVRO file format can produce one and only one column of type variant or object or array.

 Use CSV file format if you want to load more than one column.**
```

From this I understand is that it is loading all data to $1, but how can I resolve this and insert data unique on ID and VISITS to table using merge query.

Comment: Avro is semi-structured data, therefore you need to load first the Avro file into a single column of type VARIANT. After that you can select individual fields from the VARIANT using dot walk format.

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE INTO TEST USING (SELECT $1:ID ID, $1:VISITS VISITS,$1:DATE DATE, ...
```

You will have `$1` and for any columns you need to access like an object.